# How can I retrieve the value associated with an Excel Cell that is based on a formula referencing another Excel Sheet using Excel Interop?

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I am properly able to get the values of Excel cells using Excel interop with the following method:

```
public string ReadCell(object row, object column)
{
    try
    {
        if (m_Worksheet.Cells[row][column].Value != null)
        {
            return Convert.ToString(m_Worksheet.Cells[row][column].Value2);
        }
     }
     catch
     {
         //
     }
      
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

The above code works for ordinary text or number values.

When it is a formula -- for example, when I use a formula as following **no text or value** will appear: `='Data Selection'!B4`

The actual value of this cell is "Community Bank"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this problem. The `else if` case is actually what I was originally using, but it previously threw an exception in some instances (I cannot remember what the exact exception was). I will go back later and improve my answer.

```
public string ReadCell(object row, object column)
{
    try
    {
        if (m_Worksheet.Cells[row][column].Value != null)
        {
            return Convert.ToString(m_Worksheet.Cells[row][column].Value2);
        }
        else if (m_Worksheet.Cells[row, column].Value != null)
        {
            return Convert.ToString(m_Worksheet.Cells[row, column].Value2);
        }
     }
     catch
     {
         //
     }

     return string.Empty;
}
```